# Tricky A level maths question on conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I've been trying to solve this problem for the past 8 hours and still cannot come to any right answer to be honest I don't even know how to approach it so I would be very grateful if anybody could help me out with this tricky problem as no teachers were able to explain it to me.
The problem is as follows.

.There are 25 students in a school

.the number of students who study both English and history is 3

.the number of students who study neither history nor english is 14

.The number of students who study history but not English is three times the number of students who study English but not history .

Two students from the school are chosen at random given that exactly one of the two students studies English what is the probability that exactly one of the two students studies history.

Comment: You've been on MSE for some time, so you should know that we explain our work so far in well-written questions here. Haven't you been able to get started here at all? Conditional probability has a definition; have you written it down? The constituent probabilities seem likely to depend on knowing the number of students who study history but not English, and vice versa; have you calculated this?

Comment: Big hint: for any sets $A, B$ we have that $|A \cup B| = |A \setminus B| + |B \setminus A| + |A \cap B|,$ where $A \setminus B = A \cap B^C$ (those items in $A$ but not in $B$). You'll get two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: I do understand how conditional probability works and have worked out the number of each student studying only history and existential but am not quite sure how to find the probability of getting exactly one student

Comment: Exactly $25 - (14+3) = 8$ students study exactly one of the two subjects.  So (in effect) $$R + S = 8, ~~3R = S.$$

Comment: How many students study English?  (Whether or not they also study history.)  Once you know that, determine how many pairs of students exist in which exactly one studies English.  Then figure out how many of those pairs (in which exactly one student studies English) also include exactly one student who studies history.  To give you a hint, the correct answer is between $\frac 12$ and $\frac 23$.

Comment: This is not a conditional probability question. It is simply a set theory / combinatorics problem.

Comment: Draw the Venn diagram and label the four disjoint components with variables. Now you just have an algebra problem.